# Javascript to redirect, then change form information and submit changed form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I know very little about web scripting, but I imagine this is the correct route to take.

I have a forum with several themes that can only be changed by going to your profile, then settings, then changing the theme from a drop down, and clicking a "submit" button to save.

I would like to make a script that would allow the user to click an icon placed at the bottom of every page, and upon clicking, the script would redirect them to their edit profile page, change the drop down to match whichever icon they clicked, then submit the saved changes (or at least place a pop up asking them to confirm the change if the last part isn't possible)

Could anyone direct me on how to do this, please?

Answer (score 0):

Upon clicking on the icon, pass the drop-down ID that needs to be checked on next page. Also pass a flag ie. autopost=true.

On the second page.... using javascript auto-select the drop-down based on ID in query string. and check if autopost is true then submit() the form.

This is a generic list of steps. Not actual code.

Comment: As I said, I'm pretty clueless. Is there any way you could put together some code to do this for me?